# error on downloading files from Oracle UCM

Tags: python, oracle, soap, cloud

headers and soap body set right, with docID requests. see below

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/xml','charset':'UTF-8'}

body_ID="""<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ucm="http://www.oracle.com/UCM">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ucm:GenericRequest webKey="cs">
        <ucm:Service IdcService="GET_FILE">
            <ucm:Document>
                <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
                <ucm:Field name="dID">{docID}</ucm:Field>
            </ucm:Document>
        </ucm:Service>
    </ucm:GenericRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>""".format(DocID='<DOCID>')
```

getting error below on requests response

```
success
<Response [200]>
b'------=_Part_11826_1961656318.1609798653407\r\nContent-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=UTF-8;type="text/xml"\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\nContent-ID: <4522dc33-d0c7-4609-aefb-5f2768a2cde4>\r\n\r\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>\n<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><env:Header/><env:Body><ns2:GenericResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.oracle.com/UCM"><ns2:Service IdcService="GET_FILE"><ns2:Document><ns2:Field name="StatusCode">-1</ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="dID">UCMFA08693968</ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="refreshMonikers"></ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="refreshSubMonikers"></ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="IdcService">GET_FILE</ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="changedMonikers"></ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="StatusMessageKey">!csUnableToDownloadFile!csServiceDataException,DOC_INFO_SUB,QdocInfo</ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="idcToken"></ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="StatusMessage">Unable to download file. Unable to execute service DOC_INFO_SUB and function QdocInfo.\n</ns2:Field><ns2:Field name="dUser">{user replaced}</ns2:Field><ns2:
```

specific error

```
StatusMessageKey">!csUnableToDownloadFile!csServiceDataException,DOC_INFO_SUB,QdocInfo</
```

Able to login with same user/pasword and download manually

Answer (score 0):

So dID on wsdl has been set as an integer. The UCM* value is actually the docname and the doctitle would be the filename. The dID value would have to be extracted by GET_SEARCH_RESULTS by DocName.  Likewise GET_SEARCH_RESULTS for automated tag search.

Hope this helps anyone looking to get this done by python, not seeing a lot on HCM python integration.